# Как посчитать количество совпадений в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте.
Есть массив

```html
[anatolypower-pamir2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 64
                    [to_user] => anatolypower
                    [from_user] => pamir2
                    [message] => rrtt
                    [status] => 1
                    [send_date] => 2017-09-05 14:07:56
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 69
                    [to_user] => pamir2
                    [from_user] => anatolypower
                    [message] => Что такое rrtt ?
                    [status] => 1
                    [send_date] => 2017-09-05 14:14:47
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 72
                    [to_user] => anatolypower
                    [from_user] => pamir2
                    [message] => Привет :)
                    [status] => 1
                    [send_date] => 2017-09-05 18:00:21
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 73
                    [to_user] => pamir2
                    [from_user] => anatolypower
                    [message] => Получил твое сообщение
                    [status] => 1
                    [send_date] => 2017-09-05 18:00:37
                )

        )
```

Как посчитать сколько в нем совпадений где `[status] => 1` и `[to_user] => pamir2`

Comment: Это касается все того же вопроса получения последнего сообщения в группе вместо первого при GROUP BY? Я вчера изменил один из ответов на ваши вопросы и добавил туда нужный SQL. Все это любыми извращениями делается на стороне БД. Если у вас миллион сообщений в базе, тоже в массив его читать будете?

Comment: С GROUP BY все реши очень просто, создал массив диалогов пользователя и вывел. Все работает супер. Теперь вот хочу подсчитать количество входящих и исходящих сообщений. Но уже кажется решил задачу. Но пока только в мыслях.  Сейчас код собираю и протестирую. Если все ОК а по логике так и должно бить то удалю этот вопрос.

Comment: Вот запрос для того первого вопроса: `SELECT m1.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE to_send = m1.to_send) cnt FROM messages m1 LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON m1.to_send = m2.to_send AND m1.id < m2.id WHERE m2.id IS NULL;`

Comment: Для **этого** вопроса тоже все должно решаться на стороне БД. Обрабатывать массив на стороне PHP в общем случае - неправильно. Изучайте SQL или PDO. Серьезные проекты делаются на MVC, где M(odel) - самая тяжелая и важная часть, она же и работает с базой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) { 
    if($data[$i]['status'] == 1) $a++;
}
echo $a;
```

Где $data переменная с массивом. Посчитать другие данные можно по аналогии с примером.

Comment: А я вот так хотел сделать 

$sum = 0;
foreach ($data[$dialogname] as $item) {
$sum += (float) $item['status'];
}
echo $sum;

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял суть задачи, то можно обойти массив любой глубины с помощью `array_walk_recursive()`

```
echo findMatches($arr, 'status', 1);


function findMatches($arr, $key, $val) {
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($i, $k) use (&$count, $key, $val) {
        !($k == $key && $i == $val) ?: ++$count;
    });

    return (!empty($count) ? $count : 0);
}
```

Comment: @Tokwiro дописал обёртку для удобного использования.